# How to wipe the cache partition of a Samsung Tablet?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I am trying to wipe the cache partition of a [Samsung Tablet GT-P5100](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_2_10_1_p5100-4567.php) which does not start the Android operating system any more. Only the Samsung logo is displayed before it starts over.

Therefore, I launched the recovery mode and selected the menu entry `wipe cache partition` as shown on the first photo:

[image: Recovery menu]

When I press the power button the `Erasing ...` starts as shown on the second photo:

[image: Erasing starts]

Right after, the erasing is stopped by an error as shown on the third photo:

[image: Erasing errors]

Finally, an `Error!` stops the process as shown on the fourth photo:

[image: Error]

Immediately, the device restarts.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I have deleted this answer as i am not sure this Texas Instruments (TI) OMAP 4430 SoC is shipped with fastboot mode at all. Ususally Samsung devices have Odin Download mode, please follow this instructions instead
https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxytab2gmsunified.html

---

(old answer still can be viewed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/210515/4))

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I did not have a look at [TWRP](https://twrp.me) yet. I will read through, check it out and let you know if it worked for me.