# "Wipe cache partition" is not in the recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode

I am using a Motorola Edge 20 Pro running Android 13. I ran into a problem and online search told me that wiping the cache partition via the recovery mode might solve it.

When I go into the recovery mode of my phone it lists the possible actions, but `wipe cache partition` is not one of them. According to the websites I found, it should be. Any idea why the option is not available or how I can do this?

Apparently, Samsung phones only list this option in the menu if the phone is plugged in ([link](https://www.androidsage.com/2020/12/16/how-to-boot-into-recovery-mode-on-samsungs-one-ui-3-0-android-11-update/)). This did not work for me, the option also does not show when I open the recovery mode while the phone is being charged.

Comment: A lot of Android web pages you find are auto-generated using a fixed template and then for a large set of device types the same page will be generated just with a different model name. Some times the shown content really matches the device behavior but more often it doe snot match.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what the problem is that you are trying to fix.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I'm afraid this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919), and without knowing which websites you used as the reference, it might be difficult to clarify (because as Robert says, some tech webpages are auto-generated regardless of the fact, and manufacturers do often customize their Android). On the other hand, I think wiping the cache partition is possible if using *custom recovery* like TWRP, but this needs unlocking the bootloader first which will *wipe all data*.

Comment: Related regarding the Samsung link: [How to wipe the cache partition of a Samsung Tablet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210514/44325), which shows the menu but doesn't work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Many recent devices do not have `recovery` and `cache` partitions: https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/ab/ab_implement#partitions